# frama-c usage on windows 7

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, frama-c

I have installed Boron version of windows installer from frame-c website http://frama-c.com/download.html

when I try to run the val plugin, I am getting an error about preprocessor varaible CPP not being set as below:

```
C:\Frama-C\bin>frama-c.exe -val filename.cpp
[kernel] user error: failed to run: gcc -C -E -I.  -o "C:\Users\akandoor\AppData\Local\Temp\filename.cpp4f5d23.i" "filename.cpp"
you may set the CPP environment variable to select the proper preprocessor command or use the option "-cpp-command".
[kernel] user error: skipping file "filename.cpp" that has errors.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted because of an invalid user input.
```

with the -cpp-command I get the following error:

```
C:\Frama-C\bin>frama-c.exe -cpp-command 'C:\utils\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe -C -E -I. -
x c' filename.cpp
[kernel] user error: option `-C' is unknown.
                     use `frama-c.exe -help' for more information.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted because of an invalid user input.
```

ANy clues/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion: since pre-processing is causing trouble, do the pre-processing in any way that is convenient for you, saving the pre-processed file(s) as .i files. Then pass the .i files on Frama-C commandline: it will know it does not need to pre-process them then.

If you insert annotations into the .c files or want to change the pre-processing options, do not forget to re-generate the .i files.

---

Another suggestion more often addressed to people who want the last, improved Frama-C version is to install inside a Linux virtual machine. This would make everything just work. There would be a GCC in the default PATH, and this GCC would take the commandline options `-C` and `-E` to pre-process. You would be using the same environment as most of the users and developers of Frama-C. And you could have a more recent version, too.